# To regextract keywords in between [ ] but has different data variations

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i have trouble running into this formula when i have slight different variations of data. The idea is to capture the brand in between square bracket but some contains " " inside the square brackets [] contains the brand name. As per the screenshots, you will see the variations of the data.

**[Here is the link to the trix:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bwXji2r5Vhb1gw0Q2AONUvrpI_5cCQbHozgma02eYgk/edit?usp=sharing)**

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have entered the following in cell D2.

```
=index(ifna(
regexextract(A2:A4,"""(.*?)"""),
regexextract(A2:A4,"#.*?\[(.*?)\]")))
```

The formula extracts everything between the first occurrence of quotation marks `""`, if no match is found (IFNA) it extracts everything between the first pair of square brackets preceeded by `#`.

### Update

```
=index(ifna(
regexextract(A2:A5,"(?:""|'')(.*?)(?:""|'')"),
regexextract(A2:A5,"#.*?\[(.*?)\]")))
```